# How to activate @Aspect in AEM?

Tags: java, osgi, aspectj, aem

I working with java code in **AEM**.

We use maven and in **pom.xml** is exist all needed dependencies and **aspectj-maven-plugin**

I prepared aspect with pointcut:

```java
package org.xxx.aop.aspects;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.aspectj.lang.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

@Aspect
public class NodeAspect {

  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NodeAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("execution(public * javax.jcr.Node.*(..)")
  public void jcrNodeAccess() {}

  @Around("jcrNodeAccess()")
  public Object jcrNodeMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOG.info("--- LOG NodeAspect ---");
    Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    // some code
    // ..

    return result;
  }
```

But when I installed my package in AEM, my aspect does not work.

Maybe my aspect I will need to activate?

Maybe this problem related with behavior of **OSGI (felix)** in **AEM**?

Please provide to me ideas how to fix it

Comment: The aspectj-maven-plugin weaves your code at build time. Maybe it conflicts with the way you create your bundle. Can you check if the code in the jar is weaved? Additionally I am not sure if you can influence code that is not defined in your bundle. You seem to try to change the behaviour of jcr.Node which I guess is not in your bundle.

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic, yes. but log-file always is empty

Comment: Log files are never empty! Then your instance is broken.

Comment: Try creating a custom logger that watches org.xxx.aop.aspects and set it to debug or even trace level to get at least a hint where to begin the inspection and get the root cause.